# MVC 2 RenderVirtualPartial helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I would like to create a HTML helper that works the same as Html.RenderPartial except I would like the partial to be rendered from ViewData or a model object and not a file on the filesystem.

example: 
      `<% Html.RenderVirtualPartial("Name", Model.MyPartialContent") %>`

I can return string in my helper but i need to have code tags (ie <%= DateTime.Now %>) interpreted so assume I need do some kind of binary output stream writer?

thanks in advance

-Mark

Comment: What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because I want re-usable content that can be edited from a backend and which is able to make use of other helper methods i create. think similar to virtualpathprovider in terms of content stored in a database. Thanks -Mark

Comment: Ok. For this to work you will have to parse and compile the code as you have c# code in a string. This will probably be quite a lot of work. I know the spark viewengine does something like that for its views. Maybe you can check out that project and find a solution.

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like this but not sure how to get it to work like ive stated above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string/1241257#1241257

Comment: That will not really help you. That does the other way around as to what you want to do. So it doesn't have any c# code in any string that it needs to compile. I suggest you do this some other way. Maybe edit the actual .ascx file instead. If you are thinking of this for a cms or something you should rethink anyway as it will be a huge security risk as you let the user do whatever he wants (he could very easily take control of your database for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not add the futures and you can use renderAction, or you can render partial put pass a model over also